# cordova build ios without signing

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

I'm trying for some hours now to develop a continuous integration [script](https://github.com/jfoclpf/in-my-district/blob/main/.github/workflows/ios.yml) to build on iOS an Apache Cordova APP. Though I'm getting all the time signing errors.

How can I build an iOS APP with cordova without any keys nor credentials given? I tried

```
cordova build ios
cordova build ios --debug
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

After several days slightly around it, this worked successfully

```
cordova build ios --prod --release --buildFlag="CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=''" --buildFlag="CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO" --buildFlag="CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=''" --buildFlag="CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO"
```